# Reciprocal binomial coefficient polynomial evaluation

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, binomial-coefficients, symmetric-polynomials

The conventional binomial coefficient can be obtained via

$$
f(x, n) = (1+x)^n = \sum_{i=0}^n { n \choose i} x^i
$$

And the function $f$ can be every efficiently performed on evaluation.

I'm interested in evaluating value for a function $g(x, n)$ very similar to it

$$
g(x, n) := \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{{ n \choose i}} x^i
$$

With some fixed $n$, how can I convert $g(x, n)$ into a form so it can be evaluated efficiently?

Comment: According to [this paper][1] by Mansour, we have from example 1 on page 3 that
$$\sum_{k=0}^na^kb^{n-k}\binom nk^{-1}=\frac{n+1}{(\frac1a+\frac1b)^{n+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{(a^k+b^k)(\frac1a+\frac1b)^{k-1}}k.$$
Letting $b=1$, we get
$$g(x,n)=\frac{n+1}{(\frac1x+1)^{n+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{(x^k+1)(\frac1x+1)^{k-1}}k.$$
I don't think there'd be a way to get this into closed form.



  [1]: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0104026.pdf

Comment: An efficient algorithm to evaluate polynomials from its coefficient representation is [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method). Note also the coefficients can be generated by $a_n=1$ and $a_{n-k-1}=\frac{k+1}{n-k}a_{n-k}$, for $k=1,2,...,n$, where $g(x,n)=a_nx^n+...+a_0$. So, you can define $g_0(x,n)=a_n$ and iteratively, from $g_{k}(x,n)$ compute $g_{k+1}(x,n)=xg_k(x,n)+a_{n-k-1}$.

Comment: @alduan. Thanks for the link. Impressive paper.

Comment: Thanks all for the references! A side terminology question: is there a name for taking the reciprocal of coefficient of polynomials with none zero coefficients? The reciprocal polynomial is taken for reflection of coefficients

Comment: @alduan. Have a look at my edit.

Comment: When you address any comment to a specific user, include *@user_name* in the body.

Answer (score 1):

*Too long for a comment.*

@alduan gave a link to this very interesting [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0104026.pdf) but I am afraid that there is a mistake somewhere.

I think that it should be

$$\color{blue}{g(x,n)=\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{x^i}{{ n \choose i}}}= \color{red}{\frac 1 x}
\color{blue}{\frac {n+1} {\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{n+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac 1 k(x^k+1)\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{k-1}}$$ Otherwise, the first term of the expansion would be $x$ instead of $1$.

For sure, for $x=1$, the result is correct but this not the case for $x\neq1$ (easy to check).

For example, as written is the paper
$$g(x,1)=\frac{2 \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{x}+1\right)
   \left(x^2+1\right)+x+1\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{x}+1\right)^2}=x(1+x)$$

I sent an e-mail to Prof. Mansour for clarification.

**Edit**

We exchanged a few e-mails and, effectively, in the paper at ArXiv, one term is missing. The front term must be divided by $(a+b)$.

Have a look at the [final version](http://users.dimi.uniud.it/%7Egiacomo.dellariccia/Glossary/identities,%20inequalities/Mansour2002a.pdf) of the paper
$$\sum_{k=0}^na^kb^{n-k}\binom nk^{-1}=\frac{n+1}{\color{red}{(a+b)}(\frac1a+\frac1b)^{n+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{(a^k+b^k)(\frac1a+\frac1b)^{k-1}}k$$